# Drupal dynamic cache page increase

Tags: drupal-8

I have a site under Drupal 8 and I have a problem with the cache of pages that are constantly increasing. How to limit the creation of the cache which here is bigger and bigger and exceeds my DB quota.

Screenshot of DB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK1na.png

Here is the website: rjluxefurniture.be

Thanks,

Yannik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of table rows in each cache table using the following setting in your settings.php configuration file:

```
$settings['database_cache_max_rows']['default'] = 500;
```

The default setting is 5000 rows per cache table.

For more information see the Drupal change record: https://www.drupal.org/node/2891281